# Temporary communication between different subnets

Tags: networking, subnet

The product I work on has a communication network of 192.168.0 (four systems 100, 101, 102, and 103).  From time to time there is a desire to patch in a set of these systems (using their 192 addresses) to the site network to communicate using various instrumentation tools that have tight licensing that is bound to a site machine.

Apparently this poses a non-trivial route issue as 192 addresses could pop up here, there or anywhere (However only one set of 192's on the site at any one time obviously).

Thank you kindly for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A router of some sort (i.e. router or firewall) is the obvious answer to connect the two networks.  If IP address conflicts are a concern, then using NAT will prevent problems.

Always be careful when connecting development to production.  You could accidentally bind to the production database and delete a table or something...  not that this ever happens of course.

Comment: So I have the router DHCP from site and then do the NAT translation for the 192 addresses without involving the IT dept to setup VLANs.  Thank you much.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend connecting networks, routers or firewalls without involving your IT department.  You run the risk of creating a network loop or breaching security.  In many companies, doing something like this is a fire-able offense.

Comment: I agree with the statement above, however when I mentioned "not involving my IT dept" I meant, "once this solution is cleared with IT I can use it and do not require IT to setup VLANs each time I need to connect up a new set of 192 computers at a different router port".

Basically saying if they agree after that point they do not need to assist me in settig it up; I can just plug it in use it, then unplug it.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There is a [related post here](https://serverfault.com/questions/4458/private-ip-address-in-public-dns/), and here is (my)[an answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/4458/private-ip-address-in-public-dns/4681#4681) that is directly related to your issue.  In your case, routing private addresses to the public is not a concern, *although it does explain why you will have routing issues (initially)*.  The simple solution would be to look at a VPN setup that would "tie" the different networks together.  This would solve your routing problem while connecting secure all at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you need an exception for a system to jump subnets look into the [windows route](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/sw/custcosw/ps1001/products_tech_note09186a0080150baf.shtml) command. It is often the solution to these kinds of things (assuming your on a windows machine). This works especially well in a temporary situation where adding new hardware might be more cumbersome.